# Analysing boot failure: help me interpret smartctl result

Tags: boot, hard-drive

**Context:** I keep having problems with booting my single OS Ubuntu machine, when I startup my laptop I keep getting errors such as: `Checking Media - failed`, `Failure reading sector 0x... from 'hd0'`, `error: environment block too small` `Error: attempt to read or write outside disk 'hd0'`, and so on. When OS does boot up and I can use the laptop, after some time the OS blocks (possibly when I use Chrome) and crashes with wierd errors: doing sudo from terminal can result in `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Input/output error` or touchpad stops working and the icons disapear. Or I get a black screen with:

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1450: inode #20185358: comm systemd-logind: reading directory lblock 0
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1450: inode #20185828: comm NetworkManager: reading directory lblock 0
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1450: inode #20185089: comm NetworkManager: reading directory lblock 0
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1450: inode #24641537: comm acpid: reading directory lblock 0
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_find_entry:1450: inode #...: comm (tmpfiles): reading directory lblock 0
```

My system: Dell Inspiron 15R-5521, Hdd 1TB SATA3 5200 RPM, i7, 8 GB RAM, Ubuntu 16 (same happens with Linux Mint or Ubuntu Mate)

I am trying to see if it is a HDD problem or something burnt on the motherboard.

**Question:** I ran `smartctl -a` on my HDD. Can you help interpret these results for me?

```
 ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc1
    smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.8.0-36-generic] (local build)
    Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

    === START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
    Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
    Device Model:     ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
    Serial Number:    S2WZJ90CB67655
    LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 208e1e1da
    Firmware Version: 2AR20003
    User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
    Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
    Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
    Form Factor:      2.5 inches
    Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
    ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
    SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
    Local Time is:    Mon Jul 31 17:40:33 2017 UTC
    SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
    SMART support is: Enabled

    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
    SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

    General SMART Values:
    Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                        was never started.
                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
    Self-test execution status:      (  41) The self-test routine was interrupted
                        by the host with a hard or soft reset.
    Total time to complete Offline 
    data collection:        (13800) seconds.
    Offline data collection
    capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                        command.
                        Offline surface scan supported.
                        Self-test supported.
                        No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                        Selective Self-test supported.
    SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                        power-saving mode.
                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
    Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                        General Purpose Logging supported.
    Short self-test routine 
    recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
    Extended self-test routine
    recommended polling time:    ( 230) minutes.
    SCT capabilities:          (0x003f) SCT Status supported.
                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                        SCT Data Table supported.

    SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
    Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
    ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
      1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
      2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   055   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       12701
      3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   089   089   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       3467
      4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6394
      5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
      7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
      8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   015    Old_age   Offline      -       0
      9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3754
     10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   051    Old_age   Always       -       0
     11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       88
     12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   094   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       6386
     13 Read_Soft_Error_Rate    0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       259891
    191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       40
    192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       40881
    194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   064   053   000    Old_age   Always       -       34 (Min/Max 14/47)
    195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
    198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
    199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1218
    200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
    240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3579
    241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       1772620
    242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   097   094   000    Old_age   Always       -       5383346
    254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

    SMART Error Log Version: 1
    ATA Error Count: 12 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
        CR = Command Register [HEX]
        FR = Features Register [HEX]
        SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
        SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
        CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
        CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
        DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
        DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
        ER = Error register [HEX]
        ST = Status register [HEX]
    Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
    DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
    SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

    Error 12 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3731 hours (155 days + 11 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      40 51 00 00 00 00 40

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      18 9f 18 9f 18 f0 18 9f      10:54:18.685  RECALIBRATE [RET-4]
      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:00:00.029  NOP [Abort queued commands]
      60 00 08 20 6c 70 40 08      00:00:00.029  READ FPDMA QUEUED
      60 00 08 18 88 29 40 08      00:00:00.029  READ FPDMA QUEUED
      60 00 08 30 0a 10 40 08      00:00:00.029  READ FPDMA QUEUED

    Error 11 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3690 hours (153 days + 18 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      40 51 00 00 00 00 40

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      18 9f 18 9f 18 f0 18 9f      10:54:18.685  RECALIBRATE [RET-4]
      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:00:01.182  NOP [Abort queued commands]
      61 00 08 60 dc 6b 40 08      00:00:01.182  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 78 a8 cc 6b 40 08      00:00:01.182  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 08 90 55 f2 40 08      00:00:01.182  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

    Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3690 hours (153 days + 18 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      40 51 00 00 00 00 40

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      18 9f 18 9f 18 f0 18 9f      10:54:18.685  RECALIBRATE [RET-4]
      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:00:01.134  NOP [Abort queued commands]
      61 00 08 58 6e 94 40 08      00:00:01.134  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 08 20 6e 94 40 08      00:00:01.134  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 08 18 6b 94 40 08      00:00:01.134  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

    Error 9 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3448 hours (143 days + 16 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      40 51 00 00 00 00 40

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      18 9f 18 9f 18 f0 18 9f      10:54:18.685  RECALIBRATE [RET-4]
      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:00:03.447  NOP [Abort queued commands]
      61 00 a8 b0 5b 4c 40 08      00:00:03.470  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 d8 a0 6a 49 40 08      00:00:03.470  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
      61 00 f0 d0 aa 45 40 08      00:00:03.470  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

    Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3419 hours (142 days + 11 hours)
      When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

      After command completion occurred, registers were:
      ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
      -- -- -- -- -- -- --
      40 51 00 00 00 00 40

      Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
      CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
      -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
      18 9f 18 9f 18 f0 18 9f      10:54:18.685  RECALIBRATE [RET-4]
      00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08      00:00:00.035  NOP [Abort queued commands]
      60 00 08 30 0e 54 40 08      00:00:00.036  READ FPDMA QUEUED
      60 00 08 50 0b 91 40 08      00:00:00.036  READ FPDMA QUEUED
      60 00 08 70 13 51 40 08      00:00:00.036  READ FPDMA QUEUED

    SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
    Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
    # 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      3749         -
    # 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               40%      3749         -
    # 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3746         -
    # 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3745         -
    # 5  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      60%      2661         -
    # 6  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      2661         -
    # 7  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2526         -
    # 8  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      80%      2506         -
    # 9  Short offline       Interrupted (host reset)      80%      2491         -
    #10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2491         -
    #11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       254         -
    #12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         2         -

    SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
    Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
     SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
        1        0        0  Interrupted [90% left] (0-65535)
        2        0        0  Not_testing
        3        0        0  Not_testing
        4        0        0  Not_testing
        5        0        0  Not_testing
    Selective self-test flags (0x0):
      After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
    If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your hard drive doesn't appear to have any damaged sectors, so that's good. It does have a few CRC errors, which is usually fine. Do you have free disk space? Try `df -h`. That can usually cause that error. Is there anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: It's a 1 TB Hdd and I only have Ubuntu on it right now but I will double check. Can I see this if I boot from a USB with Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to mount it first.

Comment: df -h says it has 859G available. After mounting the hdd from usb ubuntu I see /var/log/demsg has only "(Nothing has been logged yet.)". Looking around the log files, if you have any suggestion it would help. One strange thing is that the hdd appears and disappears from time to time in the results of lsblk even though it is mounted. Thx!

Comment: I found something odd, I opened a new question about it if you are curious: https://askubuntu.com/questions/941655/booting-failures-syslog-recurring-error-investigation