# booting failures, syslog recurring error investigation

Tags: boot, syslog

I have some trouble booting my Ubuntu laptop, sometimes it works, most of the times it doesn't. Result of `smartctl -a` seems to be that my HDD is health so I am investigating other posibilities. Details about my system and errors are in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941443/analysing-boot-failure-help-me-interpret-smartctl-result).

I found in my syslog the recurring error bellow. Some people had the same dificulties booting the OS and found PSU was to blame or some cable. Their errors were not identical to mine though.

What do you think can cause this error?

```
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'hostname': start running ordered scripts...
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4073] Loaded device plugin: NMVethFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4073] Loaded device plugin: NMTunFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4073] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4073] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4074] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4074] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4074] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438945.4075] Loaded device plugin: NMBondFactory (internal)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039736] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x7c204 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039740] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039742] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039744] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039747] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:10:f0:f3:04/00:00:5b:00:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039747]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039748] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039750] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039752] ata1.00: cmd 60/c8:48:d8:f7:0e/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 102400 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039752]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039753] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039754] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039757] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:70:00:90:29/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 131072 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039757]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039758] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039759] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039762] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:78:60:3a:84/00:00:24:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 4096 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039762]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039763] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039764] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039766] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:80:20:ee:04/00:00:5b:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039766]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039768] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039769] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039771] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:88:e0:19:41/00:00:5e:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 4096 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039771]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039772] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039773] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039776] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:90:00:91:29/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 131072 in
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039776]          res 40/00:74:00:90:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039777] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:25 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.039780] ata1: hard resetting link
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.355550] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.368567] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   28.368596] ata1: EH complete
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438946.4377] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438946.5443] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438946.5994] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438946.7897] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171832] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x45804000 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171836] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171837] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171839] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171842] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:70:20:eb:04/00:00:5b:00:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171842]          res 40/00:f4:00:a9:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171844] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171845] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171848] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:b8:48:0b:06/01:00:5b:00:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 131072 in
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171848]          res 40/00:f4:00:a9:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171849] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171850] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171853] ata1.00: cmd 60/98:c0:f0:c4:0e/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 77824 in
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171853]          res 40/00:f4:00:a9:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171854] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171855] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171858] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:d0:70:3a:84/00:00:24:00:00/40 tag 26 ncq dma 4096 in
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171858]          res 40/00:f4:00:a9:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171859] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171860] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171862] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:f0:00:a9:29/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 30 ncq dma 131072 in
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171862]          res 40/00:f4:00:a9:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171864] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:26 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.171866] ata1: hard resetting link
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.487317] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.500370] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.500386] ata1: EH complete
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438947.4607] manager: (enp7s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438947.4616] keyfile: add connection in-memory (b5ce8d04-fd92-3051-9b9a-03e4d3a23223,"Wired connection 1")
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438947.4619] settings: (enp7s0): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 NetworkManager[908]: <info>  [1501438947.4627] device (enp7s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.689369] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915859] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x1260010 SErr 0x280100 action 0x6 frozen
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915863] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x08000000, interface fatal error
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915865] ata1: SError: { UnrecovData 10B8B BadCRC }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915867] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915870] ata1.00: cmd 60/d0:20:08:c0:0e/00:00:00:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 106496 in
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915870]          res 40/00:8c:00:d4:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915872] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915873] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915876] ata1.00: cmd 60/00:88:00:d4:29/01:00:00:00:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 131072 in
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915876]          res 40/00:8c:00:d4:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915877] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915878] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915881] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:90:78:0b:81/00:00:32:00:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 4096 in
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915881]          res 40/00:8c:00:d4:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915882] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915884] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915886] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:a8:30:e6:04/00:00:5b:00:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915886]          res 40/00:8c:00:d4:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915887] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915889] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915891] ata1.00: cmd 60/20:c0:e0:3a:84/00:00:24:00:00/40 tag 24 ncq dma 16384 in
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915891]          res 40/00:8c:00:d4:29/00:00:00:00:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915892] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
Jul 30 20:22:27 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   29.915895] ata1: hard resetting link
Jul 30 20:22:28 gabi-Inspiron-5521 kernel: [   30.231520] ata1: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
```

EDIT: HDD as described by smartctl

```
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Serial Number:    S2WZJ90CB67655
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 208e1e1da
Firmware Version: 2AR20003
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 3.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Jul 31 17:40:33 2017 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

Comment: What brand/model HDD do you have? Have these error messages be around for a long time? Did your booting problem just start? You may have a disk NCQ problem... we'll see.

Comment: This may help: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168331

Comment: @heynnema - I thought the HDD was Western Digital but it seems it is Samsung. I used Ubuntu 12 for a couple of years before these errors started. At first I rarely got an error but now I get them on almost every boot-up. I tried Ubuntu Mate 16, Linux Mint and now Ubuntu 16 and it is the same. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You may be suffering from NCQ errors on your hard disk. This is based on your syslog entries. Lets try this to fix it...

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub # edit a file
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash libata.force=noncq"
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

Then:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo update-grub # update grub
reboot # reboot the computer
```

Recheck /var/log/syslog* for new disk errors similar to the ones you posted.

```
grep -i ata1 /var/log/syslog* # search for ata1 errors
```

Comment: I did the steps until update-grub on the file in my main HDD where Ubuntu is. Then from a USB boot Ubuntu I mounted the local Hdd as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145241/how-do-i-run-update-grub-from-a-livecd). 'Though after `chroot`, the `/boot/grub` didn't have any `.mod` files, it had other files plus a `grub.cfg`. Then `sudo update-grub` gave me an error `grub-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for /dev/sdb1.  Check your device.map.` I rebooted but still got the same error on screen: `environment block too small.`

Comment: If you were booted to your HDD when you edited /etc/default/grub, why didn't you just do the next step, instead of booting to a USB? What do .mod files have to do with anything? Why are you poking around in /boot/grub anyway? Just follow my instructions and you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: The thing is I can't boot from my Hdd, I use a bootable USB with Ubuntu and then I have to mount my Hdd in such a way that I can run update-grub on that installation of Ubuntu instead of the one I was booted in. Ie. the path to the grub file I changed is <path_to_my_hdd_mount>/etc/default/grub and so on...

Comment: ah, ok, I see what you were doing now. The .mod files aren't in /boot/grub, but in a sub-directory. Try this. Can you boot to the GRUB menu on your HDD? If so, hit the `e` key to edit the boot script, and find the `splash quiet` line, add my mod, and exit/boot with F10 (check that F key), and see if Ubuntu comes up. If it does, check your edit on /etc/default/grub and do a `sudo update-grub`. Report back.

Comment: It doesn't work, it crashes before entering the grub when I boot from my internal Hdd. It seems I'll have to do this from another Ubuntu instance by mounting everithing... Somehow... :)

Comment: You'll have to retry the chroot method. I'm not an expert on that, so follow a different set of instructions than you used before, as there may have been an error there. Search here for `chroot`. If your GRUB is that badly destroyed, you may have bigger problems than we thought. Do you have a backup of your important files? You may need to reinstall Ubuntu, if the hardware isn't too far gone. If you do reinstall, you may still need my fix if you see the same errors.

Comment: I already made backups back when I could boot my pc. I will try a reinstall just to get Ubuntu working again then follow your suggestions

Comment: If you reinstall, and do get the disk errors that you got before, and my answer helps to solve the problem, please remember to accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I managed to boot my old Ubuntu and I did the steps as you described but unfortunately it didn't reboot... I will try to install the Windows 10 trial and if that doesn't work either than it must be a hardware failure... Thank you anyway, maybe it will help someone else!